# Do I need to use commit() when creating a database? And where do I put it in?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
import random
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
from urllib.request import urlopen
from collections import Counter
import re

conn = sqlite3.connect('EdwardH.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS datasources')
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS StopWords')
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS IMDB')
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS NYT')

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE datasources (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , 
datasources INTEGER, description INTEGER, sourceurl WEBSITE )')

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE StopWords(id INTEGER, Word INTEGER, Freq INTEGER)')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IMDB(id INTEGER, Word INTEGER, Freq INTEGER  )')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE NYT(id INTEGER, Word INTEGER, Freq INTEGER  )')

a1 = 0
a2 = 0
c1 = 0
count = {}
fhand1 = urllib.request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nimdvir/teaching/master/stopwords.txt')
```

for line in fhand1:
    print(line.decode().strip())

```
for w in fhand1.read().strip().split():
c1 += 1
w = w.lower();
if w in count:
    count[w] += 1
else:
    count[w] = 1
for w, freq in count.items():
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO StopWords (id, Word, Freq ) VALUES(?,?,?)', 
(c1, w,count))


print(c1)

c2 = 0
count = {}
fhand2 = urllib.request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nimdvir/teaching/master/imdb.txt')
for line in fhand2:
print(line.decode().strip())
for w in fhand2.read().split():
w = w.lower();
if w in count:
    count[w] += 1
else:
    count[w] = 1
for word, freq in count.items():
cur.execute('INSERT INTO IMDB (id,  Word, Freq ) VALUES(?, ?,?)' 
(c2,w,count))


count={}
fhand3 = urllib.request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nimdvir/teaching/master/nyt.txt')
for line in fhand3:
print(line.decode().strip())
for w in fhand3.read().split():
w = w.lower();
if w in count:
    count[w] += 1
else:
    count[w] = 1
for word, freq in count.items():
cur.execute('INSERT INTO StopWords ( Word, Freq ) VALUES(?,?)',(w,count))
```

I want to run a database through StopWords, IMDB, and NYT, but still no results. I researched about db.commit() and I'm not sure where to put it in particularly.
EDIT: I added in full code so you can see the whole thing and possibly find an issue.

Comment: Please properly format code, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need it, by default, python's `conn.cursor()` does not automatically commit your changes. `commit` is placed after all changed you want to be made already executed, to guarantee all or nothing behavior

Just place it after the last insert loop (not in the loop), then check your sqlite